# What are the holes on the backs of MegaBlocks Call of Duty characters for?

Tags: part-identification, minifigures, clone-brands

I need help with identifying this, and I'll have a lot more questions.

Comment: This question is not about LEGO products or clone-brands in relation to LEGO bricks.

Comment: According to the help center, "Bricks is for LEGO® and building block enthusiasts. If you use LEGO or one of a number of compatible systems that share similar building techniques, and need answers to your questions (or would like to answer questions about these systems), this is the place for you." Based on this, OP's question is quite valid. Can we please un-hold the question? I can answer it as I'm familiar with Mega Bloks.

Comment: @TheBrickBlogger There seems to be some discrepancies between the Help Center and the [Tour](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/tour) page which says "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about LEGO Bricks".

Comment: @TheBrickBlogger I have re-opened the question considering what is currently written in the Help Center but I think we need to review what questions are on-topic.

Comment: @CourierCouch Welcome to Bricks.SE! Most of us here focus on the LEGO brand, so I can't promise we'll have great answers for you, but your questions are welcome here. You may find yourself proselytized if all your questions are about Mega Bloks, though. :)

Comment: Thank you, @Ambo100. I think an occasional compatible brand question is not too distracting, and they can naturally come up, as many LEGO fans are collect - or at least curious about - compatible brands. Also, often people buy used lots with mixed content and questions about an item being LEGO or not can come up. Anyhow, jncraton already answered this particular question, so I only added a little extra to it in the comment section.

Answer (score 3):

The hole on the back of the figures is mostly used for backpacks and other accessories as shown here in the figure on the left:

[image: Mega Bloks tank]

In addition, it is also used sometimes to secure the figures into position. For example, in some open cockpit vehicles there is a peg at the back of the seats, that the hole on the back of the figures can attach to. This keeps the figures more secure in their position.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The hole on the back of the figures is mostly used for backpacks and other accessories. In addition, it is also used sometimes to secure the figures into position. For example, in some open cockpit vehicles there is a peg at the back of the seats, that the hole on the back of the figures can attach to. This keeps the figures more secure in their position.